# Magento 2 adding more conditions in Magento Catalog price rules

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules

I want to extend default Magento 2 functionality with a lot more features like: giving discount on the basis of custom attributes on products, giving discount on specific product, giving discount on the basis of my own attributes on products.

Is there a way I can achieve it with Magento's catalog price rules? Or should I create my own module for custom catalog price rules? If yes, how can I get UI elements like  `conditions`, `action` etc. in Catalog Price rules?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call on a spefiecie product, you should go to
store > Attributes > Product (search for SKU)

Then you turn on (Use for Promo Rule Conditions)
Storefront Properties > Use for Promo Rule Conditions

Then you could call a specific product or based on whatever Product Attributes you like

This works only for the conditions
I'm also looking into how I can create extra action any ideas?